# Consolidating Duplicate Rows into 1 Row with Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012, duplicates

I was wondering how I can take a data set that looks like this:

Table 1:

```
RecordID    Code
A   351
A   352
A   353
A   354
```

to look like this:

Table 2:

*you can already assume I created a second table with the column headers I created below*

```
RecordID    351 352 353 354 355 356
   A         Y   Y   Y   Y   N   N
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I am using SQLServer 2012

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RecordID,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 351 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' AS [351],
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 352 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' AS [352],
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 353 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' AS [353],
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 354 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' AS [354],
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 355 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' AS [355],
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 356 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' AS [356]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY RecordID
```

Comment: Thanks guys! this makes sense and should work, ill give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
select
    RecordID,
    iif(sum(iif([Code]=351,1,0))>0,'Y','N'),
    iif(sum(iif([Code]=352,1,0))>0,'Y','N'),
    iif(sum(iif([Code]=353,1,0))>0,'Y','N'),
    iif(sum(iif([Code]=354,1,0))>0,'Y','N'),
    iif(sum(iif([Code]=355,1,0))>0,'Y','N'),
    iif(sum(iif([Code]=356,1,0))>0,'Y','N')
from table
group by RecordID
```

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it. Why not just use `max(case when code = 351 then 'Y' else 'N' end)`

Comment: @Lock in this case we will depend on the order of ascii codes, what if we need to localize or use other symbols?

Comment: @Lashlane. Not sure I see what localization has to do with this? Don't get me wrong.. I'm not saying yours is in anway wrong.. just never seen it done like that and to me the intent isn't as clear. Can you explain how this affects the order of ascii codes?

Comment: @Lock your approach works only because ascii code of Y > N, for example in russian it will be vice versa (Д (yes) < Н (no)), so for russian letters you need to use min

Comment: @Lashlane Ah I see what you mean now. I didn't full understand the question!